# Storage in React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, sqlite, react-native

I'm about to develop offline dictionary app with React Native. But I'm not sure which storage is the best in React Native between `SQLite` & `AsyncStorage`. As I read some online documentation and tutorials, when I use `SQLite` I must need to configure `SQLite` library in each app `iOS` and `android`. And when I look through `AsyncStorage` not sure it can be handle or not million records inside it. That's why I like to know which one should I use between `SQLite` & `AsyncStorage` or some cool library out there for React Native?

Comment: AsyncStorage uses SQLite in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that case, I recommend using [Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-js). It is simply much faster than AsyncStorage and SQLite. Read [this](https://realm.io/blog/introducing-realm-react-native/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041999/why-is-realm-so-fast-compared-to-sqlite) for more info.

`AsyncStorage` has slow runtime and has no indexing capabilities. It accepts only strings as its value and you need to serialize data before inserting and deserialize when reading. So it's not good for large amount of data. It also has 6MB limitation for Android devices.